# Add -eglstream to Xwayland

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, xorg, wayland

I am trying to get a Wayland session running with as few bugs as possible using the nvidia proprietary drivers (I am aware this is a tall order).
Things seem to be working mostly perfectly for me, with the exception of apps running in Xwayland.
In particular, these apps stutter / display previously rendered frames (particularly when typing). This is a known bug, and tracked at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1317.

For chromium apps, I have noticed that adding `--use-gl=egl` as a command line argument nearly completely fixes this issue. However, not all Xwayland apps support this argument, so I cannot simply add it to everything that causes problems.

From the help page for `Xwayland`, I learned about the option `-eglstream`, which encourages Xwayland to "use eglstream backend for nvidia GPUs". This sounds like exactly what I want. My problem is that I have not found any way to pass the `-eglstream` argument to the default `Xwayland` instance used on the wayland session of Gnome.

Immediately after a fresh login, `ps aux | grep Xwayland` shows that `Xwayland` is not running yet.
If I then start an app that runs through `Xwayland`, I see a process:

```
/usr/bin/Xwayland :1 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.0GRD41 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -initfd 7
```

The parent process ID points towards `gnome-shell`, leading me to believe that this is what is responsible for auto-starting `Xwayland`.

If I try to run my own Xwayland instance with the new arg, I get the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/Xwayland :1 -rootless -eglstream -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.0GRD41 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -initfd 7
(WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Please use "-listenfd" instead.
(WW) Option "-listen" for file descriptors is deprecated
Please use "-listenfd" instead.
Failed to initialize glamor, falling back to sw
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot write display number to fd 6
(EE) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I get the same output whether I run the above command before `Xwayland` has been autostarted (i.e. just after a fresh login, before running any apps) or after, with the other instance already running.

Is there a way to configure `gnome-shell` to add the argument I want? Or perhaps to replace a running instance of `Xwayland`?

Specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2
- NVIDIA RTX 3050 using the `nvidia-driver-530-open` drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong before, it is not `gnome-shell` that autostarts `Xwayland`, but rather `mutter`. I was able to add the `-eglstream` argument by patching the [source](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/gnome-42/src/wayland/meta-xwayland.c#L881) and compiling myself. To do this, I followed the script at https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded/blob/main/ubuntu/package.sh (instead of applying the patches in the repo, I just manually edited the file).

It did stop the flickering, but at a very steep performance cost. The effect was almost identical to setting `XWAYLAND_NO_GLAMOR` or `MUTTER_DEBUG_FORCE_EGL_STREAM=1` as recommended by https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1317. I suspect the latter of these two may even be doing exactly the same thing.